# Download from an URL in Spring

Tags: java, spring, download

I want that , by pasting the URL of a file (the file can be an image, an Xhtml, or a Css) into a form of a JSP, this can be downloaded form internet and saved locally. Please can you help me ?

Answer (score 4):

```
you can use this to open URL in the browser and save into the file location.
<%
String site= contain the string(URL);
response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location", site);   
File file = new File("/Users/asdf.xml");  
FileWriter fr = null;
BufferedWriter br = null; 
URL url = new URL(site);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

fr = new FileWriter(file);
br = new BufferedWriter(fr);
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
br.write(line);
br.newLine();
}
reader.close();
br.close();
%>
```